# ActionBar Customization

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I am trying to create a custom layout which centers the title and changes the background color of actionbar but that' what I am getting:

[image]

Could you please tell me what I am doing wrong?

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    //actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
     actionBar.setIcon(
                new ColorDrawable(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.transparent)));
    actionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
    actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
    //actionBar.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);

    LayoutInflater inflator = (LayoutInflater) this .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View v = inflator.inflate(R.layout.actionbar_layout, null);

    actionBar.setCustomView(v);
}
}
```

actionbar_layout.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
android:background="#00ffff"
android:orientation="horizontal">

<TextView
    android:text="title"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:id="@+id/text"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/> 

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've run into this one wayyy too many times (only on 3.0+ devices, to my knowledge), and, as a result, you should try adding these calls with the ones you're already using (which I've included):

```
    actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);     
    actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
    actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(false); 
    actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
    actionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
```

That should remove the left-spacing that's automatically applied.

Comment: Thank you, Guardanis. =) One more thing, textView is not in the center, although I used  android:layout_centerHorizontal="true". Do you know why?

Comment: Since your TextView's Width is set to match_parent and the width of its parent is set to fill the width of the screen, the TextView's width is also the width of the screen. So you can either set the TextView's width to be wrap_content with the layout_centerHorizontal attribute, or you can just apply android:gravity="center" on the TextView. I would probably go with the former, though